# Customize a custom element javascript file created from Angular 8 using another script tag

Tags: javascript, angular, angular8, custom-element

I'm working on creating an embedding widget using Angular 8 custom element. I made a button and gave a function when clicking on it. After building my project I got a script file which can be placed on any website with the custom element tag.

```html
<conv-widget></conv-widget>
<script src="../elements/conv-widget.js"></script>
```

Now I want to change the color of my button using a script tag. While putting it beneath the original script file, its not changing the color as the page would have already been loaded.

But If I put it above the code still its not working as its giving an error that button ID is null.

```html
<conv-widget></conv-widget>
<script src="../elements/conv-widget.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var btn = document.getElementById('button');
    btn.style.backgroundColor="#232323";
</script>
```

or

```html
<conv-widget></conv-widget>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var btn = document.getElementById('button');
    btn.style.backgroundColor="#232323";
</script>
<script src="../elements/conv-widget.js"></script>
```

I even tried to use the same code in the main script file which has been created. Still its not coming.

```html
<conv-widget></conv-widget>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var Bd = Ur("ng-component", gu, $d, {}, {}, []), qd = tr({
    encapsulation: 3,
    styles: [
        ["#button{background-color:#000;}"]
    ],
    data: {}
});
</script>
```

This isn't working for me. Kindly help me by giving any way to solve this problem.

Content of conv-widget is :

```html
<ng-container *ngIf="!show">
<button (click)="toggle()" id="button">
</button>
</ng-container>
```

CSS code of conv-widget is :

```css
#button {
   background-color: rgb(193, 0, 61);
    border-radius: 50%;
    height: 60px;
   width: 60px;
  }
```

I am trying to change the color of button using a new script tag.

[Screenshot of Console error which I'm getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6rGjY.png)

Comment: without seeing the source code of your ``<conv-widget>`` it is going to be a stab in the dark...What happens when you do the ``getElementById`` and style color from the DEV console? (or in a ``setTimeout``)

Comment: I have given the source code with the error which I'm getting, can you help me out.

Comment: If the ``button`` inside ``ng-container`` is in shadowDOM, then any ``document.xxx`` call will never be able to read inside shadowDOM. One solution is to add a method on your ``ng-container`` to set the style (inside) Read up on shadowDOM